# Watson Studio Data Refine

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I have two questions regarding the data refinery process in WS.

I have 200 Columns of data and when it was first loaded into the platform, by default everything is in the string type. How do I

1. Change columns in a batch
2. Specify the data type when I am uploading the data as using a CSV format file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the first question, you can use operations (in *Code an operation...*) available from the [dplyr R library](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/refinery/code_operations.html). For example, in order to convert all double columns to the Double Type, you can use something like this:

```
mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(as.double(.x)),.x,as.double(.x)))
```

As for the second question, I think this is not possible, as long as you upload the data directly via browser.